# Radicals in a fraction: simplification

Tags: calculus

I cannot for the life of me figure out how this fraction got simplified. Please tell me how the first fraction got simplified into the second one. I've provided initial fraction and its simplified answer: 
$$
-\frac{p \cdot (-1 /(2\sqrt{517-p}) )}{\sqrt{517-p}} = \frac{1}{2(517-p)}
$$

Comment: There is a fraction in the numerator.  The denominator of the fraction in the numerator gets multiplied by the radical in the denominator of the bigger fraction.  That is it.

Comment: The negative is missing in the simplified fraction so there must be something missing...

Comment: Thanks Chris. It was just as easy as multiplying the denominator to the big fraction :)

Answer (score 1):

First, write $\sqrt{517 - p}=r$. Then you have
$$
-\frac{p\frac{-1}{2r}}{r}\,.
$$
From here it should be obvious what to do, but I like multiplying top and bottom of the *main fraction* by $2r$ and letting the minus signs cancel. That gives $p/2r^2$, in other words $p/(2(517 - p))$

Comment: Very nice, concise, explanation. You describe well the thought processes I use for exactly this kind of problem.

Comment: Thanks Lubin! It was easier than I thought. Just a simple multiplication of the denominator to the main fraction.

Answer (score 0):

$$ -\frac{p \cdot \frac{-1}{2\sqrt{517-p}}}{\sqrt{517-p}} \\\\$$
$$ -\frac{p \cdot -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{517-p}}}{\sqrt{517-p}} \\\\$$
$$ --\frac{p \cdot \frac{1}{2\sqrt{517-p}}}{\sqrt{517-p}} \\\\$$
$$ \frac{p \cdot \frac{1}{2\sqrt{517-p}}}{\sqrt{517-p}} \\\\$$
$$ \frac{\frac{p}{2\sqrt{517-p}}}{\sqrt{517-p}} \\\\$$
$$ \frac{p}{2\sqrt{517-p} \cdot \sqrt{517-p}} \\\\$$
$$ \frac{p}{2(517-p)} \\\\$$

Which step does not make sense to you?

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks! Did you type it or put it into an application that does the steps for you?

Comment: @MiltonFriedman, I typed it up. (I did it a little deliberately so you could see it, normally I would probably just go from step 1 to 5 to 7.)

Comment: I totally get it now.